# error 404 when part of the mappings from spring controller are acessed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

In the controller below, wheh I try access an url mapped by the methods `pagina(...)`, `produto(...)` or `categoria(...)`, I am getting an error 404. But, if try access any one of the other mappings, all goes without problem. Anyone can see what I am missing here?

```
@Controller
public class AcessoController {
...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("categorias", lista.categoria());
        model.addAttribute("produtos", lista.produto());
        model.addAttribute("paginas", lista.pagina());
        return "public/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/${pagina}")
    public String pagina(Model model, @PathVariable("pagina") String pagina) {
        model.addAttribute("pagina", view.pagina(pagina));
        model.addAttribute("paginas", lista.pagina());
        return "public/pagina";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/produto/${id}")
    public String produto(Model model, @PathVariable("id") String id) {
        model.addAttribute("produto", view.produto(Integer.valueOf(id).intValue()));
        model.addAttribute("paginas", lista.pagina());
        return "public/produto";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/categoria/${nome}")
    public String categoria(Model model, @PathVariable("nome") String nome) {
        model.addAttribute("categoria", view.categoria(nome));
        model.addAttribute("produtos", lista.produto());
        model.addAttribute("paginas", lista.pagina());
        return "public/pagina";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signin")
    public String signin(Model model) {
        return "acesso/signin";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup")
    public String signup(Model model) {
        return "acesso/signup";
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in who you have defined the path variable in the mappings.

Change your code to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{pagina}")
public String pagina(Model model, @PathVariable("pagina") String pagina) {
    model.addAttribute("pagina", view.pagina(pagina));
    model.addAttribute("paginas", lista.pagina());
    return "public/pagina";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/produto/{id}")
public String produto(Model model, @PathVariable("id") String id) {
    model.addAttribute("produto", view.produto(Integer.valueOf(id).intValue()));
    model.addAttribute("paginas", lista.pagina());
    return "public/produto";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/categoria/{nome}")
public String categoria(Model model, @PathVariable("nome") String nome) {
    model.addAttribute("categoria", view.categoria(nome));
    model.addAttribute("produtos", lista.produto());
    model.addAttribute("paginas", lista.pagina());
    return "public/pagina";
}
```

Note that I have removed `$` in the mappings

Comment: OK, now I see I put an `$` which don't belong there :(

Comment: Exactly! Remove it and the problem goes away!